# How to start flex development

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to learn flex development, however I meet some problems:

1  The official site.

I googled `flex`, then I got `Adobe flex` and `Apache flex`.

I want to know which owns the official support, I have heard that adobe donated the flex to apache. If so, then which should be the main development site?

I mean where can I get the documents, SDK , and IDE ?

2 The development manner.

I have found a tutorial which use the Flex 2, from the tutorial, it seems that I have install `jdk`, `eclipse`, `tomcat`, `flex sdk` and etc.

So I want to know if the `flex` is still bounded with java?

3 The language

Will the `Action script` be the main development language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to answer your doubts. 
You can find lots of examples about Adobe flex development just typing on google flex tutorials.

You can Download the SDK from here http://sourceforge.net/adobe/wiki/Projects/.
And Eclipse here http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. And add the SDK in Window -> Preference -> Flex -> Installed Flex SDKs -> Add

Adobe flex is a group of technologies that can help you to create RIA applications. When you are programming with FLEX you use tags called MXML and a language called ActionScript that it's very similar to JAVA.

If you would like to integrate with other programming languages you should used AMF (Action Message Format).

[image]

Comment: It's a little bit confusing with the versions these days;-) Adobe donated Flex to Apache, so all new Releases will be from there: flex.apache.org. Current Release is 3.10. (last Release from Adobe is 3.6) However, AIR-Runtime and SDK are still maintained by Adobe (current Release 3.8) You will need these when you want to create 'native' applications that don't require a browser to run. IDE-wise IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate also has Actionscript / Flex support (just as alternative), but is free only for open source projects. For commericial use you must buy a license.

Comment: @T.Richter The current Apache Flex release is 4.10 and the last Adobe Flex release was 4.6.  I assuem that was just a typo on your part.

Comment: @Reboog711 Yeah, typo ... as I said, confusing ;)